# Running long Python script on AWS, nohup and screen don't prevent breaks

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gnu-screen, nohup

I'm running a Python script that's parsing through several million xml files and dumping content into a csv. The entire process will take somewhere close to a week to complete, so I'm trying to run it entirely on an AWS server. The problem is that I tried using screen and nohup to get the process to run even when I disconnect from ssh, but often I come back and find that the process has broken either because of a server timeout or a broken pipe error. I thought that nohup and screen were designed to prevent these things from happening and just let the process run until it's complete. Am I missing something or doing something wrong? I can paste my code if it'd be helpful. Thank you for any advice you might have!

Comment: `nohup python script.py &` will run the script and continue it even if you close the shell, but if you want it running for a week I'd recommend writing the code such that it's tolerant to crashes (can pick up where it left off after restart) and use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to make sure it's always running.

Comment: Aside from the server timeout or broken pipe error, this question may be a little broad for SO, but you also *may* find some help in the Python chat, as far as pointers on making a long-running process.

Comment: Could the broken pipe be caused by you trying to write to stdout on the client? I would try redirecting my prints to a file and make sure that you are running the process in the background. `nohup python script.py 1>log.txt 2>log.err &`...I don't think `screen` has any real benefits to contribute here.

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone! I will try out some of these suggestions and report back if I can come up with a more specific question.